# webmatrix code to populate a list of queries from database based on selected input

Tags: webmatrix

Am kindof new to the webmatrix environment,am working on an online admission system where in my databasee,i have populated the number of courses that is being availabe based on department.

in my html form,i want to implement a scenario wherby as the users chooses a department,i then list out all courses belonging to that department that the user can choose from.i have no idea on how to go about this.i would be glad if someone helped  me out.

Comment: Help you out with what? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: yes i do actually.am working on an online admission system using webmatrix.i have a form where the user should choose a particular category and a list of options will display from my database according to the category. i dont want to achieve this when posting the form.iam just looking for a demo code using jquery to retrieve the from my database and place the results in a textbox.would be very grateful

Comment: You need cascading dropdownlists for that: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/196/webmatrix-jquery-cascading-dropdown-lists